# os.execute not working with love2d

Tags: lua, shared-libraries

I'm trying to use os.execute(), but I'm getting this problem:

```
attempt to call field 'execute' (a nil value)
```

I've done `os = require 'os'` but when I do: `os.execute("mkdir" .. var)` it's giving me the above error.

From what I've worked out, it's because it's not calling in all of the stuff from os, but I've looked and I can't figure out how to call in everything from os. In python i'd do `from os import *` but I don't know the code for lua. I've tried using `package.loadlib('os', 'execute')` but that didn't work. :/

EDIT: I did a separate test with love2D, and it worked. so I can't see why this isn't working...

Comment: are you sure you don't have code somewhere that is overwritting/reassigning the os.execute function in the problem script? do you have any local table objects named os?

Comment: ohhh right! I've got os = "NT"/"unix". That explains why it's not working :D. Thank you! I'll rename the variable now :)
EDIT: You ought to add that as an answer.

Comment: How do I close the topic?

Comment: there should be a delete option under your post if you wish to delete the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you sure you don't have code somewhere that is overwritting/reassigning the os.execute function in the problem script? do you have any local table objects named os?

Comment: Thanks, this helps. I've renamed my os variable to host :3

Comment: ahhh, the beauty of dynamic languages letting you clobber built-in libraries :P

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
require 'os';
if package.loaded['os'] and type(package.loaded['os']) == "table" then
  local os = package.loaded['os'];
  --from here use the local os variable to call anything inside os.
  --main block of code
end
```

I hope this works for you.